# how to use mysqldump?

Tags: linux, mysqldump

I want to copy my database `qdbase` server. It is located at:

```
qa@qaubuntu:~$ /var/lib/mysql/qdbase
```

On the client PC, I want it located at:

```
qa@qadesktop:~$ /home/qa/html
```

Everyone tells me to use mysqldump. How do I use that because I've never learnt how to use that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following is just an example to use mysqldump.

```
cd /home/qa/html
mysqldump --host="hostname" --user="username" --password="password" databasename > backup_name.sql
```